# Is there a better way to write nested if statements in java

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I'm writing a program where users can search for a directory, file, or both. Using checkboxes to determine what the user wants to do. Later down the road I may add another option, and the code my look ugly with all the nested if statements.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (directories.isSelected()) {
  if (files.isSelected()) {
    return file.isDirectory() || file.isFile();
  }
  return file.isDirectory();
} else {
  if (files.isSelected()) {
    return file.isFile();
  }
}
```

is there a more simpler way to do this?

Comment: If `directories.isSelected()` and `files.isSelected()` are both false, what's it supposed to return? Or can that never happen?

Comment: I have a return true at the end, just forgot to add that in there. So, if nothing is selected then it always returns true

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `return (directories.isSelected() && file.isDirectory()) || (files.isSelected() && file.isFile());`

EDIT: That returns false if `directories.isSelected()` and `files.isSelected()` are both false. To make it return true in that case, stick a `|| !(directories.isSelected() || files.isSelected())` on the end.